# HP PROLIANT ML110 RAID 1 don't rebuild

Tags: raid, hp-proliant

I have an HP Proliant ML110 G5 with RAID1 mirror. One disk is dead and I took a new disk (same size, rpm and model) and put on the bay, BUT the system doesn't see it... I believed that I had only to put the disk in .... where il the problem ... Should I format the disk before the rebuilding?...

Help! thanks to everyone who could give me some idea to solve... (sorry for my poor english... :)

Nicola

Answer (score 1):

You could either have a bad second disk, or something other than the disk could be bad: the backplane, the cable between the backplane and the controller, or the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting and pressing F1 at the 1786 Recovery Needed message.

Allow time for the rebuild to complete before booting the OS.

See [RAID 1(+0): breaking mirrors and rebuilding drives](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00378986/c00378986.pdf%20%22RAID%201%28+0%29:%20breaking%20mirrors%20and%20rebuildind%20drives%22)